# External link within an internal link - React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I try to set up an external link in a block containing itself an internal link, managed with react-router.
The problem is that when I click on the external link, I'm not redirected to the external link but to the internal link of the block.

1- Here is my base code, without the link surrounding my item :

```
<li className="projects__item">
    <div className="projects__item-logo">
        <Link to={`projects/${id}`}>
            <img className="projects__item-media" src={Rocket} alt={name} />
        </Link>
    </div>
    <div className="projects__item-entry">
        <h3 className="projects__item-title">
            <Link to={`/projects/${id}`}>
                {name.substr(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}
            </Link>
        </h3>
        <a href="test.com" target="_blank">
            TEST
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

2- And the code with the link surrounding my li, in order to improve the UX :

```
<Link to={`projects/${id}`}>
   <li className="projects__item">
    <div className="projects__item-logo">
        <Link to={`projects/${id}`}>
            <img className="projects__item-media" src={Rocket} alt={name} />
        </Link>
    </div>
    <div className="projects__item-entry">
        <h3 className="projects__item-title">
            <Link to={`/projects/${id}`}>
                {name.substr(name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}
            </Link>
        </h3>
        <a href="test.com" target="_blank">
            TEST
        </a>
    </div>
   </li>
</Link>
```

Does anyone have any ideas, please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the click event will be handled by react-router and never by the browser default navigation functionality. Effectively clicking on the link you've made is the same as if if you didn't put the anchor tag in there. You can either have a react-router link or a native anchor tag. You need to choose one or the other. Can you explain why you are trying to use both?

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem is, in my case, I actually have a project item block. In this block, I have two items, an item that contains an internet link and an item that contains an external link.  
To improve the UX, I want to put the internal link on the projects item block.